# How to get a list of my AWS EC2 Instances

Tags: amazon-ec2

I need to export the list, that I get from AWS EC2 Console, of EC2 instances I have to a CSV/excel or similar.

It has to be in reports but cannot find it.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [Resource Groups](https://console.aws.amazon.com/resource-groups/).

> 1. Resource Types: AWS::EC2::instance
> 2. Search resources
> 3. Export search results to CSV

Update 11/2020: It is not possible to list all resources by type any longer. You have to either specify tags or Cloudformation stacks to create a resource group.

Comment: can this answer be made better - I see you are pointing to a way - however if I go to dashboard which OP has pointed I dont find the steps you are mentioning here

Answer (score 11):

With the AWS CLI you can use the following command (Linux):

```
aws ec2 describe-instances \
    --filters Name=instance-state-name,Values=running \
    --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].{Name:Tags[?Key==`Name`]|[0].Value,Instance:InstanceId,Type:InstanceType}' \
    --output text >> instances.csv
```

This will export the instance fields in tab-separated lines that you can later import into Excel.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way I have found is to configure your view with all the fields you want, then, select (highlight with mouse) all the fields and copy and paste them into excel

Answer (score 0):

You can export list of all your instances as csv using [Resource Groups & Tag Editor](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ARG/latest/userguide/tag-editor.html)!

I can't find a way to filter by Instant State though, I'm not sure if this is possible.

[AWS console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdOQo.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

regions=$(aws ec2 describe-regions --query "Regions[].RegionName" --output text)

for region in $regions; do
    echo "Checking region: $region"
 
    aws ec2 describe-instances \
        --filters Name=instance-state-name,Values=stopped,running \
        --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].{Region:'$region', Name:Tags[?Key==\`Name\`]|[0].Value, Instance:InstanceId, Type:InstanceType, State:State.Name}" \
        --output text \
        --region $region >> instances.csv

    echo "Finished checking region: $region"
done
```

This helps in getting all the instances in the account using AWS CLI.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).